# getting null in alert text on clicking approve button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here is Script-

```
function gettext() {    
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr"); 
    var $text = $row.find(".id").text();
    alert($text);
}
```

here is html code-

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="id">
        <%=u.getMid()%>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%=u.getName()%>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%=u.getEmailId()%>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%=u.getStatus()%>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success bnt-sm" onclick="gettext()">Approve</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger bnt-sm">Reject</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

let me know why its not working

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you're using an `on*` event attribute to call the function. This means that `this` will refer to the `window`, not the clicked element.

To fix the issue you can improve your code by removing the `on*` attribute and binding the event handler using unobtrusive JS code. Try this:

```js
$('.btn-success').click(function() {
  var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
  var $text = $row.find(".id").text();
  alert($text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td >1</td>
    <td class="id">Mid</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>EmailId</td>
    <td>Status</td>
    <td>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success bnt-sm">Approve</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger bnt-sm">Reject</button>
    </td>   
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that if you have a parent `form` element then you may need to stop the form submission, depending on your intent when clicking the submit buttons. I'd also suggest giving each of them a `name` attribute so you can identify which was clicked when the request is sent.